# open text files from browser in external application

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-chrome

I am developing in zend on my local machine.  When i get an error i am shown the link to the php file that gave me the error.  What i would like to do is be able to click on that link and have the file open in sublime text 2 so it would same me some time.  I have installed the chrome extension LocalLinks to get the browser to open local files but the php file only opens in the browser. Any ideas on this?

Thanks.

LocalLinks:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida

Answer (score 1):

Why you just simply use CTRL+P (CMD+P in Mac) to open the file you need in sublime by just typing a little part of the name?

Comment: thanks I think i will start using that.  I was just hoping to be able to click the error, it would have been a bit faster. thanks.